# Why am I getting unsafe retained?

Tags: objective-c

I've just starting out with obj-c and I created 2 files, a .h and a .m file. The .h file is..

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface CardUnit : NSObject
{
@private 
    NSString *_name;
    NSString *_gold;
}
@property (nonatomic, assign) NSString *name;
@property (nonatomic, assign) NSString *gold;
@end
```

and the .m file is

```
#import "CardUnit.h"

@implementation CardUnit

@synthesize gold  = _gold;
@synthesize name = _name;

@end
```

But it's giving me 2 errors on the @synthesize lines, which are...

"Existing ivar "_gold" for property gold with assign attribute must be __unsafe retained" and the same for name.

Comment: Check this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8368157/existing-ivar-title-for-unsafe-unretained-property-title-must-be-unsafe-un

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the error i see you are using ARC, Automatic Reference Counting .

Basically you can get rid of all the @synthesize statements and even the private declarations of the ivar's name and gold is not necessary.

All you need is the CardUnit.h to be like this :

```
@interface CardUnit : NSObject

  @property (assign) NSString *name;
  @property (assign) NSString *gold;

@end
```

The Xcode compiler will take care of the rest.

See also [this reply on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8368157/existing-ivar-title-for-unsafe-unretained-property-title-must-be-unsafe-un?lq=1)

Comment: Note that `@synthesize` is still required with the stable version of Xcode (4.3). Also, it's a bit odd that the OP is using `assign` in these property declarations; they should probably be `copy` or `strong`.