# Objective-C existing instance variable must be __unsafe_unretained error

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

Same code are already questionned here, but I deal with a different problem that I can't solve myself probably because i'm new with Objective-C, so I decide to ask the question :)

webberAppDelegate.h:

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>
#import <WebKit/WebKit.h>

@interface webberAppDelegate : NSObject <NSApplicationDelegate> {
    NSWindow *window;
    WebView *webber;
}

@property (assign) IBOutlet NSWindow *window;
@property (assign) IBOutlet WebView *webber;

@end
```

webberAppDelegate.m:

```
#import "webberAppDelegate.h"

@implementation webberAppDelegate

@synthesize window;
@synthesize webber;

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification {
    NSString *urlString = @"http://www.apple.com";
    // Insert code here to initialize your application
    [[webber mainFrame] loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]]];
}

@end
```

So, in webberAppDelegate.m, here's my problem with this fraction I suppose:

```
  @synthesize window;
  @synthesize webber;
```

who give me this long error:

```
Existing instance variable 'window' for property 'window' with  assign attribute must be __unsafe_unretained
```

and pratically the same for other var "webber":

```
Existing instance variable 'webber' for property 'webber' with  assign attribute must be __unsafe_unretained
```

Thanks for your help, I really appreciate Stackoverflow community for days !!

Comment: I think you will find the same question answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8368157/existing-ivar-title-for-unsafe-unretained-property-title-must-be-unsafe-un/8368240#8368240

Comment: Note that the `assign` attribute and the `unsafe_unretained` attribute mean the same thing.

Answer (score 5):

The default ownership qualification for instance variables in ARC is `strong`, and like @robMayoff mentioned assign is the same as `unsafe_unretained` so your code reads like the following:

```
@interface webberAppDelegate : NSObject <NSApplicationDelegate> {
   __strong NSWindow *window;
   __strong WebView *webber;
}

@property (unsafe_unretained) IBOutlet NSWindow *window;
@property (unsafe_unretained) IBOutlet WebView *webber;
```

As mentioned in the linked answer provided by @Firoze, the property declaration and iVar should have matching ownership qualification. So the solution would be to make the `__strong` in the above code to `__unsafe_unretained` or to remove the instance variable declarations completely so that the compiler takes care of it.

*The same solution is provided in the linked answer in the comment. Just adding some info.*